# Cohomology of conic bundle 3-folds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-geometry, hodge-theory

It is known that for a smooth cubic 3fold $X\subset \mathbb{P}^4$ we have $H^3(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ (or if you prefer $H^{0,3}(X)=0$). Moreover, if I project off a line $l\subset X$ I can resolve the map to a conic bundle $\pi:Bl_l(X) \to \mathbb{P}^2$ with the same property.

Question: do all 3-fold conic bundle have $H^3(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$?

Comment: A conic bundle is uniruled, and every uniruled variety in characteristic $0$ has Kodaira dimension $- \infty$. In particular $H^0(X, \, \omega_X)=0$, hence for a $3$-fold  $H^3(X, \, \mathcal{O}_X)=0$ by Serre duality.

Comment: Another way to explain this is by noting that the derived pushforward of $O_X$ to the base $B$ of the conic bundle is $O_B$, so $H^3(X,O_X) = H^3(B,O_B) = 0$.

Comment: I wonder if there are counterexamples in positive characteristic, where uniruledness of $X$ *does not* imply $\textrm{kod}(X) = -\infty$ in general.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: I think my argument works in positive characteristic as well.